# Querying all entities regardless of type

Tags: fiware-orion

Using the ".*" pattern all the entities of a given type 
can be queried. E.g, to get all the entities of type "Room" the 
following queryContext can be used:

```
{
    "entities": [
    {
        "type": "Room",
        "isPattern": "true",
        "id": ".*"
    }
    ],
    "attributes" : [ ]
}
```

However, how can I get all the entities from CB regardless of type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the manual, an empty type is equivalente to "any type" (see ["Using empty types" section](https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide#Using_empty_types)).

Thus, to get all entity in all types you could do the following queryContext:

```
{
    "entities": [
    {
        "type": "",
        "isPattern": "true",
        "id": ".*"
    }
    ],
    "attributes" : [ ]
}
```

However, take into account that CB could be storing a huge number of entities (which would produce a huge HTTP response for that query), thus querying all them is in general a bad idea.

Comment: Duh! Thanks! That is exactly what I was after